# Troubles with Counter Object

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

I have a file contains Unicode strings , I am counting  the words and sorting it using   `Counter` Object

This is my code

```
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

with io.open('1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    words =infh.read()
    Counter(words)
    print Counter(words).most_common(10000)
```

This is my 1.txt file

```
വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍ വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍ വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍  വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍    വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍   വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍   വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍ വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍
```

It provides me  character counts instead of  word counts 
like this

```
[(u'\u0d4d', 63), (u'\u0d24', 42), (u'\u200d', 42), (u'\n', 26), (u' ', 21), (u'\u0d30', 21), (u'\u0d33', 21), (u'\u0d35', 21), (u'\u0d15', 21), (u'\u0d3e', 21)]
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: `words = infh.read().split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Counter` takes an iterable of elements in it's constructor. `infh.read()` returns a string which returns individual characters when iterated over. Instead, you need to provide a list of words: `Counter(infh.read().split())`.

If you want to later on write the counts into a file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10000):
        f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count))
```

Comment: Ok, How can I write this counts to a file?

Comment: @karu, Considering `f` has been opened in `wb` mode: `for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10000): f.write('{} {}\n'.format(word, count))`

Comment: File "/home/akallararajappan/corpus/counter.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.write('{} {}\n'.format(word, count))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @karu, try adding a `u` modifier to the format string.

Comment: `u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf-8')` should do the trick.